Role Table Selection in AWS CPC
Is this the right way to think about route tables? I feel like every explanation I find online is missing details on how to find the route table for outbound packets.
if a packet is inbound to the VPC, we find the route table based on the following references:
packet ip address > subnet > route table

if a packet is outbound from an EC2, we find the route table based on this reference:
EC2 ip address > subnet > route table

In both cases:
If the target is local, we route the packet to the machine inside the VPC (even in another subnet.

If the target is not specified, the packet is dropped

If the target is specified as something specific like a NAT (even in another subnet) it is routed there.

I would like to try and test this out a bit, but the route tables always come with an entry for the  VPC CiDR as target.  I see that I can change them to route to an instance but I haven't quite figured that outyet.
